# How can I make a element disappear by className in React.JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a theme selector in React. But when I use

```js
document.getElementsByClassName[0].style.setProperty("display", "none");
```

to make the element disappear, it returns

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'setProperty' of undefined`.

Is there a way to fix this error or another way to make the element vanish? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to get an element with [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) you need to pass the classname as an argument, like so

```
document.getElementsByClassName('test')
```

Then, you can try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].style.setProperty("display", "none")
```

A little snipped:

```js
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document
    .getElementsByClassName("test")[0]
    .style.setProperty("display", "none");
});
```

```html
<div class="test">element</div>
<button id="button">Hide it</button>
```

Comment: I would use document.querySelector always insted of the dated getElementsByClassName

Comment: OP was having an issue with `getElementsByClassName` and that's the reason my answer has it too :) but yeah, there are a few ways to get DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming you have `class="0" - don't. Even though you can, do not use numeric IDs and Classnames
- Change to a better classname like theme
- Use document.querySelector(".theme") to get the first,
- Use document.querySelectorAll(".theme") to get to them all.

You can use

```
document.querySelector(".theme").style.display="none";
```

or

```
document.querySelector(".theme").style.setProperty("display","none");
```

to hide it

If you do not use flex, you can also do

```
document.querySelector(".theme").setAttribute("hidden",true)
```

Comment: Even if the class was "0", OP would still need `.getElementsByClassName(0)[0]`

Comment: No `.getElementsByClassName("0")[0]`

Comment: Still giving me the error ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null```. I'm using ```document.querySelector(".dark").style.display="none";```